# Unable to select a value from a drop-down in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Im trying to select a value from dropdown :

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_ddl_sheet_name" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__ddl_sheet_name">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="tbl_E_RATES">E RATES</option>
        <option value="tbl_F_RATES">F RATES</option>
        <option value="tbl_B_RATES">B RATES</option>

    </select>
```

But none of these commands are working

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$_ddl_sheet_name > option[value='B_RATES']").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__ddl_sheet_name']/option[text()='B RATES']").click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__ddl_sheet_name > option[value='B_RATES']").click()
```

ERROR :-

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__ddl_sheet_name']/option[text()='B RATES']"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`B_RATES` is a link text of `option` but not it's `value` (value is `tbl_B_RATES`). Try this one:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select/option[text()="B RATES"]').click()
```

**UPDATE**

`NoSuchElementException` issue could be caused by page rendering completion delay. Try `Explicit wait` to wait until element is present on page:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//select/option[text()="B RATES"]'))).click()
```

**UPDATE 2**

Target drop-down menu located inside an `iframe`, so you need to switch to it first and then handle required elements:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@src="http://rate.poultrybazaar.net/show_rates.aspx"]'))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select/option[text()="BROILER RATES (WEST BENGAL)"]').click() # Replace text with required value
driver.switch_to_default_content() # to quit from iframe
```

Comment: Im getting "TimeoutException: Message:" on your new code.  BTW this is the page im scraping http://www.poultrybazaar.net/poultryrates/daily-rates/   Need to select "Sheet Name" , "year", "Month" = "BROILER RATES", "2012", "January"